# AngularJs - How can i Display the answer only when the Answer is Correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

First i will explain what i have implemented so far :-
User will select an answer in radio buttons and hit “Check answer” which would display 1. text Correct (Green) or Incorrect (Red) in first answer field and 2. the actual correct answer in the “Solution”(answer) field (Green).
My issue is It should display the solution(answer) field only when the answer is Correct . Right now the solution(answer) appears even when the answer is wrong.

Please check the link below for sample : -
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRoLXo

```
    <div data-ng-app="epubApp">
<div data-ng-controller="checkBoxFillinCtrl" data-ng-init="checkBoxData='p50';fillinBlankData='p50';">
<div class="quiz" id="quiz_1">
    <div class="question">
        <h4>1. A 6 m ladder of 20 kg rests with upper end on a smooth wall and lower end on a rough horizontal ground as shown below. Determine the minimum coefficient of friction so that the ladder does not slip?</h4><p class="qimage"><img src="../images/22.png" alt="images"/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-object multiple-choice">
        <div class="acontainer" style="margin:0em 1px 2px 1px;border:0px solid;">

                 <div id="check_box_table" >
            <table id="q_table" class="f1" data-ng-class="{'check_box_disabled':inputDisabled}">
                <tbody >

                    <tr>

                        <td  style="border:0px solid black;"><span class="check_box cElement"  data-check-box="cb[0]" data-quest-index="0"  data-check-index="0"></span></td>
                        <td >0.14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td  style="border:0px solid black;"><span class="check_box cElement" data-check-box="cb[0]" data-quest-index="0"  data-check-index="1"></span></td>
                        <td >0.29</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td  style="border:0px solid black;"><span class="check_box cElement" data-check-box="cb[0]" data-quest-index="0"  data-check-index="2"></span></td>
                        <td >0.19</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td  style="border:0px solid black;"><span class="check_box cElement" data-check-box="cb[0]" data-quest-index="0"  data-check-index="3"></span></td>
                        <td >0.35</td>
                        </tr>




                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
            <div id="correct1" style="border:1px solid gray;border-radius:5px;color:#616360;background-color:#F3F3F3;margin:1em 0em 2em 1em;font-size:100%;padding:10px;width:80%;">
                <b>Correct or Incorrect?</b>
                <!-- Replace each correct text in the below paragraphs -->
                <td><span class="result" data-ng-class="cb[0].resultClass"></span></td>
            </div>
            <div id="feedback1" style="border:1px solid gray;border-radius:5px;color:#616360;background-color:#F3F3F3;margin:0em 0em 2em 1em;font-size:100%;padding:10px;width:80%;">
                <b>Solution</b>
                <!-- Replace each feedback in the below paragraphs -->
                <p class="feedback-text">

                </p>
                <p data-ng-show="answerVisible" class="feedback-text">
Consider the FBD of the ladder<br/>
 <br/>
A = Normal reaction at lower end<br/>
B = Normal reaction at upper end<br/>
f = frictional force acting at horizontal surface<br/>
W = weight of ladder = 20 * 10 = 200 N<br/>
Considering horizontal and vertical equilibrium<br/>
f = B<br/>
A = W <br/>
So A = 200 N<br/>
Taking moment about lower end<br/>
B * 6 * sin 60&#176; - W * 6/2 * cos 60&#176; = 0<br/>
B * 6 * &#8730;3 /2 = 200 * 3 * &#189; = 300<br/>
B * 3 * &#8730;3 = 300<br/>
B = 100/&#8730;3 = 57.74 N<br/>
f = &#181; * N = B<br/>
&#181; = coefficient of friction <br/>
N = normal reaction = A = W = 200 N<br/>
f = &#181; * 200 = 57.74<br/>
&#181; = 57.74/200 = 0.29


                </p>
                <p class="feedback-text">
                </p>
                <p class="feedback-text">

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submitcontainer">
        <p style="text-align:left;">
            <div class="submit1" style="z-index:2;">
            <!-- <button id="submitBtn" style="background-color:#4f81bd; border-radius:5px; color:white; font-size:15px; padding:8px;" type="button">Show answers</button> -->
                <button class="resetBtn check"  style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:white;background-color:#616360;font-size:100%;padding:5px;margin-top:1em;margin-right:1em;"  data-ng-show="resetVisible" data-ng-click="onReset()">RESET</button>
            <button class="submitBtn reset" id="reset_1"  style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:white;background-color:#616360;font-size:100%;padding:5px;margin-top:1em;margin-right:1em;"   data-ng-show="submitVisible" data-ng-click="onSubmit()">Check Answer</button>


        </div>
        </p>
    </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

An explanation with sample would be really helpful , thank you.

Comment: Enlighten us about what you tried thus-far, aside your main code you provided, to solve it yourself by editing it into your question and not in comments!... its called "showing effort" and is a good medicine against down-voters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is of `$scope.answerVisible = true;`

You need to remove `$scope.answerVisible = true;` from the `submit` 
 function because it is making your **div** **visible** every time you click on the **Check Answer** button function.

So what I have done, I put it in the right place.

In the `validate` function you validate the answer so if it is correct then set `$scope.answerVisible` to true otherwise false;

**Here is updated function:**

```
 function validate() {
  allCorrect = true;
  data.forEach(function (val, index) {
  $scope.cb[index].clickable = false;
  $scope.cb[index].showClass = [];
  var groupCheckCorrect = $scope.cb[index].checked.length ? true : false;
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    $scope.cb[index].checked.forEach(function (v, i) {
      if (v) {
        if (val.indexOf(i) > -1) {
          $scope.answerVisible =  true;                   
          $scope.cb[index].showClass[i] = 'correct';
        } else {
          $scope.cb[index].showClass[i] = 'wrong';
          allCorrect = false;
          groupCheckCorrect = false;
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    $scope.cb[index].checked.forEach(function (v, i) {
      if (v) {
        if (val == i) {
          $scope.answerVisible =  true;                 
          $scope.cb[index].showClass[i] = 'correct';
        } else {
          $scope.cb[index].showClass[i] = 'wrong';
          allCorrect = false;
          groupCheckCorrect = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.cb[index].resultClass = groupCheckCorrect ? "all_correct" : "all_wrong";
});

/** for fill up */
$scope.inputDisabled = true;
angular.forEach(fillup_data, function (d, i) {
  if ($scope.fill[i] != undefined && d.toLowerCase() == $scope.fill[i].toLowerCase()) {
    $scope.fillResult[i] = fillup_correct;
  } else {
    $scope.fillResult[i] = fillup_wrong;
  }
});
user_fill_answer = [];
user_fillResult_answer = [];
angular.copy($scope.fill, user_fill_answer);
angular.copy($scope.fillResult, user_fillResult_answer);
/** */
```

}

Comment: Pleasure!! Keep Asking!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will say you are not using good practices as you are storing answer on frontend never store this kind of information as if the user is even little technical he/she will expose the answer and kind of hack which make the system insecure

When there is the change in option make an API call check and validate the answer if the answer is correct add a class using ng-class and vice-versa if it wrong.

So, go for this approach as it will not going to expose your correct answer to the user, if you stuck somewhere please post

Comment: Thanks for the quick response . Actually I am creating this for Epub which is basically EPUB is an e-book file format with the extension .epub that can be downloaded and read on devices like smartphones, tablets, computers, or e-readers.. So everything will get encrypted when we convert html to  epub  . 
Solution to this problem would  be really helpful

Comment: Sure I will give me sometime i will post